# sixteen digit colour code?

Tags: debian, xfce, powerpc

I am trying to convert the mac4lin awn theme from 0.3 to 0.4 so it will work in my awn. But I'm not sure about the colour codes in the 0.4 files. They are not normal hex codes, they are sixteen digits and look like this:

```
ghistep1 = #f2f2caca00001212
ghistep2 = #f2f2caca00001212
```

The ones in the 0.3 look like this:

```
glass_histep_2 = FFFFFF00
glass_histep_1 = FFFFFF2C
```

How do I convert the colour codes? What are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the gamma is the same, you can take each 8-bit part of the 32-bit color code, and handle it as unsigned in the range 0 to 255.  Multiply it by 257 (not 256) (or add it to itself shifted left by 8 bit positions).  This gives you values in the range 0 to 65535 in intervals of 257.  That should look the same complete with 8-bit like contouring.  The alpha channel MAY need different processing.  Then reconstruct it as the 64-bit color code.  How you do this depends on your programming language.

Answer (score 2):

They're 64-bit RGBA codes in the form `RRRRGGGGBBBBAAAA`. Simply scale the smaller colors to fit. Although the smaller colors *may* work once they're completed.

Comment: thanks, but how do i `simply scale the smaller colors to fit`?

Comment: Do you take the first 2 digits? The last 2? take RRRR/FF?(this is the one I would try first, btw)

Comment: @KevinM I don't know about Mac4lin themes specifically, but usually the color RRGGBBAA would expand to RR00GG00BB00AA00 (fraction of 0x10000 instead of 0x100).

Comment: @gadgetmo: take the first two hex digits as they are the most significant digits. Think about a scoring system where people score from 0 to 100 and how you would convert that to a score from 0 to 10. Apply the same technique.